# Is there anyway to change location accuracy value on Google Chrome when using Developter tool?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, google-geolocation, google-developer-tools

I've been trying to find different ways to spoof location on Google Chrome.
One of the ways is to use Developer tools (sensor settings).
The thing is with this method, Google allows me to choose a location from a preset or enter the lat, long. But whatever I choose, the accuracy value is always 150.
Is there any way I can change the accuracy value?
Thank you!
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49m3h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question and the answer
in android, in service locations (holding the GPS pin) go to app permissions, find chrome, click it and click "use precise location"

That way I got from precision 2000 to precision 10 on my page.

hope it still helps after all this time